# Agregar marcador especifico a una localización Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

¿Cómo podría añadir un marcador personalizado en Google maps?

Actualmente el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Quisiera saber cómo añadirle a cada "location" un icono diferente en vez del tradicional de Google maps.

Comment: Está en la documentación, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple?hl=es-419

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu pronta respuesta ya estuve viendo algunos articulos en la documentacion que me has enviado pero no logro adaptarla al codigo que tengo actualmente.

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta y explica con claridad que estás haciendo y qué error específico encuentras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir la imagen personalizada para cada lugar al array con información de localizaciones:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, "http://i.imgur.com/GyqbZzs.gif"],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, "http://i.imgur.com/LTCOHYH.gif"],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, "http://i.imgur.com/4CCFNWR.gif"],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, "http://i.imgur.com/dRIZ8LN.gif"],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, "http://i.imgur.com/WjZlFve.gif"]
];
```

Y luego cuando creas el marcado, especificas la imagen con el parámetro `icon` (en este caso sería el quinto elemento del array, así que usarías `locations[i][4]`):

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: locations[i][4]
  });
```

Así cada localización tendrá su icono personalizado. El código completo se vería así:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, "http://i.imgur.com/GyqbZzs.gif"],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, "http://i.imgur.com/LTCOHYH.gif"],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, "http://i.imgur.com/4CCFNWR.gif"],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, "http://i.imgur.com/dRIZ8LN.gif"],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, "http://i.imgur.com/WjZlFve.gif"]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: locations[i][4]
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado.

Comment: ¡Argh! te me has adelantado con las locations. Creo que la ruta de la imagen tiene que ir con comillas simples `'` (aunque creo que con javascript no importa, pero para mantener sus declaraciones del primer elemento) :) Y si citas la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple?hl=es-419) aún mejor =P

Comment: @MiquelColl ¿Comillas simples? A mí me funciona con comillas dobles, en JavaScript no debería importar cuál de las dos uses

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple?hl=es-419) que toledano te ha [comentado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23010/agregar-marcador-especifico-a-una-localizaci%C3%B3n-google-maps#comment36856_23010) es sencillo:

Definimos un marcador por cada localización:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, 'ruta/a/tu/imagen1.png'],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, 'ruta/a/tu/imagen2.png'],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, 'ruta/a/tu/imagen3.png'],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, 'ruta/a/tu/imagen4.png'],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, 'ruta/a/tu/imagen5.png']
];
```

En tu definición del `marker` haces:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: locations[i][4]
});
```

Comment: Gracias, he añadido  "icon: image" y he puesto una nueva linea añadiendo "var image = ''url.png" y ya me modifica el marcador, pero no a las diferentes localizaciones.

Comment: ¿Sólo te modifica 1? Creo que tienes que declarar el `marker` dentro del `for`.

Comment: Me modifico las 4 localizaciones perfectamente, pero mi idea principal es que cada localización tenga un marcador diferente, ejemplo: localizacion 1 = Azul, Localizacion 2, Verde.

Comment: Entiendo :) ahora añado lo que comentas.